# Use of Parameter and Signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I am a relatively new Python learner. So, while going through different coding techniques, I came across this:

```
from inspect import Parameter, Signature

def make_signature(names):
    return Signature(Parameter(name, Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD) for name in names)

class Structure:
    list_fields = []
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for name, val in zip(self.list_fields, args):
            setattr(self, name, val)

class Stock(Structure):
    __signature__ = make_signature(['name', 'shares', 'price'])
    #list_fields = ['name', 'shares', 'price'] 

class Point(Structure):
    list_fields = ['x', 'y']

obj2=Point(20,40)
obj1=Stock('googl', 100, 8000)
print(obj1.name)
```

I understand the `Structure` class and its integration with the `Point` class which is inheriting `Structure` class hence it's `__init__` method. But when I create object of `Point` class it doesn't support **Positional arguments** but the `Stock` class object does support the feature.

- Can anyone please explain to me why & how this happens?
- When to use Parameter, Signature?
- Also how is this related to meta programming?
- Some more examples like this.
- what is the use of `Parameter` function in `make_signature` method and what `make_signature` method is doing?
- The flow of the program i.e which function is returning to whom and vice-versa. To my knowledge the `Stock` class and `Point` class are calling the `Structure` class but when does the `make_signature` method comes in?

And I tried to read some documentation about `Signature` but those examples aren't of this kind and is too much heavy stuff for me as I keep getting lost backtracking this code documentations also I couldn't find any good explanatory documentation on Meta programming in Python.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please explain to me why & how this happens?

Both classes *only* accept positional arguments as dictated by `*args` in `Structure.__init__`:

```
s = Stock('pos_arg1', 'pos_arg2', 'pos_arg3')
p = Point('pos_arg1', 'pos_arg2', 'pos_arg3')
```

The difference is that `Stock` doesn't actually *set* any arguments because, since you commented out `list_fields`, `Structure.__init__` will use `Structure.list_fields` which is empty. That is why trying to access `name` on a `Stock` instance raises an `AttributeError`.

In both cases, `list_fields` **limits** what arguments can be set. For the `Point` instance in the previous snippet, `x` will equal `pos_arg1` and `y` will equal `pos_arg2`; `pos_arg3` is essentially tossed. This is due to `zip` which builds tuples until one of the iterables is exhausted:

```
for i, j in zip(['x', 'y'], ['pos_arg1', 'pos_arg2', 'pos_arg3']):
    print(i, j)
```

Prints:

```
x pos_arg1
y pos_arg2
```

When an empty list is supplied, it doesn't even loop. This is what happens when you initialize `Stock`, `Structure.list_fields = []` is used:

```
for i, j in zip([], ['pos_arg1', 'pos_arg2', 'pos_arg3']):
    print(i, j)
```

Prints nothing so no `setattr`s are going to get called.

> When to use Parameter, Signature?

When you want to support further introspection of your classes (or, callables in the general case) you could add a `__signature__` attribute to your class (as is done with `Stock`) and get it picked up by tools like `inspect.signature`, i.e:

```
inspect.signature(Stock)
Out[16]: <Signature (name, shares, price)>

inspect.signature(Point)
Out[17]: <Signature (*args)>
```

Signature tries to see if the object has a `object.__signature__` and if so constructs a representation of the signature when called.

Furthermore you could `bind` a signature to self and get it to support `POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD` arguments.

In general this will only present itself as requirement in very few cases. In short: you'll know if you'll need it.

> Also how is this related to meta programming?

This specific example isn't related. You could enhance it with meta programming as you'll see in the presentation I'll link.

> Some more examples like this.

This is too broad of a request. But your example comes from david beazly's metaprogramming presentation, [here's the presentation](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2013/python-3-metaprogramming.html).

> To my knowledge Stock function and Point function is calling Structure class but where does the make_signature method comes in?

Both `Stock` and `Point` use `Structure.__init__` which will populate the instance dictionary with attributes defined in `list_fields`.

`__signature__ = make_signature([...])` is executing *when the class is being created*, Python executes the body of the `class` when it encounters it. `make_signature` is going to get called and create a `Signature` object and the assignment to `__signature__` is going to be made.

Comment: Can you please explain me what is the use of Parameter function in make_signature method and what make_signature method is doing? Can you also tell me the flow of program ie which function is returning to whom and vice-versa.

Comment: Updated my answer @NiladriSekharBasu. Take note that your question is already 5 questions in one, you can't continuously update it to request more information; that's what *new* questions are for.